# Place Flutter widget with custom shape perfectly in another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to display the frame of a smartphone (SVG Image) and display any widgets in it that should not go beyond the frame of the smartphone.

[image]

In the image above I have the frame in a `Stack` and on top a `ListView` with `Cards` as child widget. The frame must be below the child widget for gestures to work. The `ListView`'s width is limited with a `SizedBox` with hardcoded width, but with that it's not responsive. On a slightly smaller screen, the `ListView` exceeds the frame (as you can see in the image). How can I make sure that the child widget always stays in the frame even if the screen size changes.

I also tried using `ClipPath` but I couldn't fit it perfectly into the frame. But I think `ClipPath` is needed because I want to place other child widgets in the frame e.g. Video that should cover all the space in the frame.

Comment: what problems did you have with`ClipPath`? what was your custom clipper?

Comment: I didn't manage to position the ClipPath exactly in the frame (maybe because I'm new to Flutter) and I also didn't get the problem with adjusting the size on different screen sizes solved.

i extracted the inner line of the frame as svg path and used it as path in clippath. See here: https://github.com/jriegraf/clippath_test/blob/main/lib/phone_widget.dart

Comment: `Path path = parseSvgPath('M 329.22 ....  m 0 0'); final matrix = sizeToRect(Size(329.555, 714.149), Offset.zero & size); return path.transform(matrix.storage);` - get `sizeToRect` from https://gist.github.com/pskink/6ef88df64d7764fd0efcd60aa618f0c0#file-size_to_rect-dart-L16

Comment: The Size looks pretty good, and I managed to get it working using the sizeToRect function. But the ClipPath still doesn't scale on smaller screens. I updated the project, you can check it out (see GitHub link above)

Answer (score 0):

To make a widget responsive you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` which takes the width of your screen in pixels, if you multiply for example by 0.7 it will occupy 70% of your screen.

```
//square widget 1:1
SizedBox(
  child: SvgPicture.asset('lib/your.svg'),
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
),
```